# How to detect if a port is already in use server side (in C++ on windows)?

Tags: c++, windows, sockets, networking, server

It's certainly a common question, but not in this terms (windows, server side, accept multi connexion).

My goal is to accept to start a server listing on a port for multiple connections only if before that the port is detected "unused".

At the line where I put `//HERE...`, `bind`doesn't return a `SOCKET_ERROR` status as I expected.
Maybe I'm doing something wrong.

How to detect that my port is not in use by some other app?

Here is the status of the port before running (it is used)

```
netstat -an
  TCP    127.0.0.1:2005         0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
```

I hope this snippet is sufficent to explain what I'm doing, it's a merge of several steps.

```
WSADATA WSAData;
int err = WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &WSAData);

SOCKADDR_IN sin;
socklen_t recsize = sizeof(sin);
int one = 1;

SOCKADDR_IN* csin;
SOCKET csock = INVALID_SOCKET;
socklen_t crecsize = sizeof(SOCKADDR_IN);
int sock_err;

if (m_socket != INVALID_SOCKET)
{
    memset(&sin, 0, recsize);
    if(m_blocal)
        sin.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_LOOPBACK);   
    else
        sin.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);

    sin.sin_family = AF_INET;                       
    sin.sin_port = htons(m_iPort);

    setsockopt(m_socket, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, (const char*)&one, sizeof(int));
    sock_err = bind(m_socket, (SOCKADDR*)&sin, recsize);
    //HERE I want to be sure no one else runs on this port

    //rest of the code using: select(m_socket + 1, &rd, &wr, &er, &timeout);
}

closesocket(m_socket);
WSACleanup();
```

Comment: Maybe one solution is a dummy client which tries to connect on localhost but cancels at acknoledgment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't set `SO_REUSEADDR`. Then `bind()` will fail if the address is already in use and `WSAGetLastError()` will return `WSAEADDRINUSE`.

Also note that two processen can still bind to the same port if the IP addresses are different, for example, one process binding to `localhost` and another process binding to the LAN network address.

Comment: I thought `SO_REUSEADDR` was to be able to re-listen on the same port (like, for multiple incomming connexions). Without any effect at the 1st one.

Comment: With sockets you `bind()` once and then you can `accept()` one or more connections. `accept()` returns a new socket that you use to communicate. `SO_REUSEADDR` allows different processes to `bind()` to the same port and that is usually not what you want or should do.